# red5: can i make shared objects read only on the client side?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, red5, shared-objects

I'm using shared objects for a chat application, but i want my red5 to monitor every string that comes in. how can i make sure that the client side won't be able to modify the shared objects ?

In my case the client side is written using adobe flash builder beta 2 (flex4)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

seems that i need to use `registerSharedObjectSecurity`

http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/org/red5/server/adapter/MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter.html#registerSharedObjectSecurity%28org.red5.server.api.so.ISharedObjectSecurity%29

to register a ISharedObjectSecurity class with restrictions to my shared object.

http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/org/red5/server/api/so/ISharedObjectSecurity.html

gonna post a full answer while i'll test it.